# PowerShell, how do I increment variable names?

Tags: variables, powershell

I am currently writing a PowerShell script that parses an XML file, and it saves some parsed values as variables for use later.

For example, say my XML looks like this,

```
<head>
  <foo>
   <bar id="1" status="dead">
      <baz>
        <qux>Hello World 001</qux>
      </baz>
    </bar>
   <bar>
      <baz>
        <qux>Hello World 002</qux>
       </baz>
   </bar>
  </foo>

  <foo>
   <bar id="2" status="dead">
      <baz>
        <qux>Goodbye World 001</qux>
      </baz>
    </bar>
   <bar>
      <baz>
        <qux>Goodbye World 002</qux>
       </baz>
   </bar>
  </foo>
</head>
```

Currently, my script looks like this,

```
[xml]$report = Get-Content ./helloworld.xml
$foo_sub_length = $report.head.foo.length - 1
$bar_sub_length = $report.head.foo[$foo_sub_length].bar.length - 1
$foo_looper = 0
$bar_looper = 0
```

As of right now, this part works, however, because I would like to pull the id number, or the qux string from each individual foo, I would like to do something similar to the following (pseudocode):

```
do {
    do {
      $foo($foo_looper)_id = $report.head.foo[$foo_looper].bar[$bar_looper].baz.id
        $foo($foo_looper)_bar($bar_looper)_qux = $report.head.foo[$foo_looper].bar[$bar_looper].baz.qux
      $bar_looper = $bar_looper + 1
    while $bar_looper <= $bar_sub_length
     }
  $foo_looper = $foo_looper + 1
while $foo_looper <= $foo_sub_length
}
```

I realize this may not have made any sense, or that I may not have been clear, but I would like some assistance. Essentially, is there a way to increment a variable so that it's name could be, for example, $foo1, $foo2, $foo3, etc, without changing it's value? Essentially,

```
> $bar = 1
> $foo($bar) = hello
> $bar + 1
> $foo($bar) = world
> $foo(1)
hello
> $foo(2)
world
```

Comment: (I would recommend just using arrays/dicts, if possible. "Variable variables" are hard to deal with as a collection.)

Comment: Would you be able to go into more detail? Unfortunetly, I quite literally just started using powershell two days ago, so this is my first real attempt at it

Comment: see (chose as "first goggle hits") http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/variables-arrays-hashes/ (see the "Arrays" section), http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html , and http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/12/06/add-modify-verify-and-sort-your-powershell-array.aspx and also hash tables: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx , http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/archive/2012/03/11/chapter-4-arrays-and-hashtables.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [New-Variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849913.aspx) cmdlet.

E.g.

```
$bar = 1
New-Variable "foo$bar" "Hello,"
$bar = $bar + 1
New-Variable "foo$bar" "World!"
"$foo1 $foo2"
```

Should give you

```
Hello, World!
```

Comment: How would I increment the name of the variable though?

Comment: Would you happen to know if it is at all possible to add multiple modifers to it? E.g. foo$bar_someinfo_$qux? so that when I for example, will have foo1_someinfo_1 and foo1_someinfo_2 be different variables?

Comment: Use the magic "$()" structure:
    > $bar = 1
    > $qux = 2
    > "foo$($bar)_someinfo_$($qux)"
    foo1_someinfo_2

Answer (score 1):

You want to rename a variable? Variables are exposed as a provider, via the variable: drive. As a result, you can use rename-item on variables, just like files.

```
ps> rename-item variable:var1 var2
```

Comment: Well, I would like to create a new variable name based on another variable. For example

> $bar = 1  
> $foo($bar) = hello  
> $bar + 1  
> $foo($bar) = world  
> $foo(1)  
hello
> $foo(2)
world

Apparently I can't format comments

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use an array? I think that's what you really want. http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html