# Value of a Variable as Part of the Name of a Variable

Tags: variables, powershell

I'm still kind of new to Powershell and I want to know if it's possible to use the value of a variable as a part of the variable name.

```
$a = "Stuff";
$abc???_def;  # ??? = It's where I want to use $a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with New-Variable:

```
$a = "Stuff"
New-Variable -Name "abc$($a)_def" -Value 'This is abcStuff_def'
Get-Variable abc*


Name                           Value                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                 
abcStuff_def                   This is abcStuff_def
```

But I suspect a hash table might be a better choice:

```
$abc = @{}
$a='Stuff'
$abc.$a = 'This is abcStuff_def'
$abc


Name                           Value                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                 
Stuff                          This is abcStuff_def
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the way to do it is to use `New-Variable` syntax.

For your example, you would do

```
New-Variable "abc&a_def" "value"
```

For more info, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849913.aspx

Much credit goes to fsimonazzi for his answer to this question:
[Powershell, how do I increment variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433729/powershell-how-do-i-increment-variable-names?rq=1)